# Rotate Object around point and move it along sine function

Tags: unity-game-engine

First off: I am very new to Unity, as in VERY new.

I want to do the following: I want to rotate a cube around a stationary point (in my case a camera) with a radius that is adjustable in the inspector. The cube should always have its Z-axis oriented towards the camera's position. While the cube is orbiting around the camera, it should additionally follow a sine function to move up and down with a magnitude of 2.

I have some working code, the only problem is an increase in distance over time. The longer the runtime, the higher the distance between the cube and the camera.

Here is what I currently have:

```
 void Awake()
 {
         cameraPosition = GameObject.FindGameObjectWithTag("MainCamera").transform;
         transform.position = new Vector3(x: transform.position.x,
                                          y: transform.position.y,
                                          z: cameraPosition.position.z + radius);
         movement = transform.position;
 }
```

I instantiate some variables in the Awake()-method and set the cube's position to where it should be (do you instantiate in Awake()?). I'll use the Vector3 movement later in my code for the "swinging" of the cube.

```
 void Update()
 {
         transform.LookAt(cameraPosition);
         transform.RotateAround(cameraPosition.position, cameraPosition.transform.up, 30 * Time.deltaTime * rotationSpeed);
         MoveAndRotate();
 }
```

Here I set the orientation of the cube's z-axis and rotate it around the camera. 30 is just a constant i am using for tests.

```
void MoveAndRotate() 
{
         movement += transform.right * Time.deltaTime * movementSpeed;
     
         transform.position = movement + Vector3.up * Mathf.Sin(Time.time * frequency) * magnitude;
}
```

To be quite frank, I do not understand this bit of code completely. I do however understand that this includes a rotation as it moves the cube along it's x-axis as well as along the world's y-axis. I have yet to get into Vector and matrices, so if you could share your knowledge on that topic as well I'd be grateful for that.

Comment: For your last question I'm not really sure myself, stackoverflow has a really active community but I never really asked question just googled them. Therefore I had a share of good advise on stackoverflow as well as the Unity forums.

Oh and just because you started on Unity I always like to recommend Brackeys on YT. He's really good and his make a game series was also my first Unity game.

Comment: Believe me, I went through a whole lot of googling today. I think my main problem is that I have yet to become fluent in the mathmatics that these problems need. I'm already watching Brackey and tried to grasp some of his concepts. Nevertheless thanks to you kind sir.

Comment: No problem I always like to see more people getting into game dev and just so you know Brackeys even made a little series where he talked about Game Maths might be something for you :D https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=wXI9_olSrqo.

Comment: I'm not really sure what the question being asked here is... If the part after "Edit" is meant to be a self-answer, it should be posted as an answer, not an edit to the question. [See here for more information](https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer).

Comment: @Ruzihm Thank you for informing me. Still new to SO, so I thought editing my post would suffice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems like I have found the solution for my problem, and it is an easy one at that.

First of all we need the initial position of our cube because we need to have access to its original y-coordinate to account for offsets.

So in Awake(), instead of

```
movement = transform.position;
```

We simply change it to

```
initialPosition = transform.position;
```

To have more readable code.

Next, we change our MoveAndRotate()-method to only be a single line long.

```
void MoveAndRotate() 
{
        transform.position = new Vector3(transform.position.x,
                                         Mathf.Sin(Time.time * frequency) * magnitude + initialPosition.y,
                                         transform.position.z);
}
```

What exactly does that line then? It sets the position of our cube to a new Vector3. This Vector consists of

```
its current x-value
our newly calculated y-value (our height, if you want to say so) + the offset from our original position
its current z value
```

With this, the cube will only bop up and down with distancing itself from the camera.

I have also found the reason for the increase in distance: My method of movement does not describe a sphere (which would keep the distance the same no matter how you rotate the cube) but rather a plane. Of course, moving the cube along a plane will automatically increase the distance for some points of the movement.

Answer (score 0):

For instantiating variables in Awake it should be fine, but you could also do it in the `Start(){}` Method that Unity provides if you wanted to.

For the main problem itself I'm guessing that calling this function every frame is the Problem, because you add on to the position.

```
movement += transform.right * Time.deltaTime * movementSpeed;
```

Would be nice if you could try to replace it with this code and see if it helped.

```
movement = transform.right * Time.deltaTime * movementSpeed;
```

Comment: That would work if I only wanted the cube to "bop". But setting the Vector and thus the position of the cube to a single position everytime only causes the cube to vibrate (because I call RotateAround() first). The distance however does not grow larger, so it seems to have something to do with the way I rotate the cube around the camera.

Comment: So if i understand it correctly when you make the change I suggested the ball distance isn't growing larger but you don't have the intended "boping" anymore?

Comment: It kept the bop, but it didn't rotate around the camera anymore. Distance also swayed, but I have found the reason for that.

Comment: Nice to now is the increase in distance still there or gone now as well? If you fixed it please explain why and write it as a response and mark it as solved (there is nothing worse than finally finding someone with the same problem that just says solved it myself lol)

Comment: It is still there, but that should be fine for now. I'd probably have to get into Quaternions to rotate that around a sphere, but I think I should first be learning how to properly work with Vectors lol. It's one of my first scripting tasks in my school, so my teacher should be more than content with my result.

Comment: You're doing Unity in school damn I'm envious :D